# SED help: how to substitute a string with another containing square brackets

Tags: replace, sed

I am using OSX and I'm having a problem while trying to replace a string in a file using the sed command. The problem is that the substitute string contains a square bracket.
In particular I want to replace this string  "message--------------" (- are blanks)
with this one "message------[ yea ]"

but if I type

```
sed "message              /s//message     \ [ yea ]" filein > fileout
```

I get this message: bad flag in substitute command: '['

I tried to put a \ before the [ but it didn't work. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Your sed command is not well formed, but I get a different error message, "invalid command code m".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/message    /&[ yea ]/g' filein > fileout
```

The `&` is the expression matched. No special treatment is needed for the brackets.

It wasn't really clear to me how the spaces were intended to be handled. The above just adds `[ yea ]` to the end of the fixed-length sequence of spaces. Should it be preferred to replace the last spaces of an arbitrary-length sequence of spaces with `[ yea ]`, a more complicated command is needed:

```
sed 's/\(message \{1,\}\)       /\1[ yea ]/g' filein > fileout
```

The idea in this case is to match a pattern that has two parts. First is a group, bracketed by `\( \)`, which looks for the `message` followed by one or more spaces (`\{1,\}`. This must be followed by exactly seven spaces. When matching text is found, it is replaced by the text of the group (the `\1`, indicating the first group) followed by `[ yea ]`. The strategy here can be adapted to other search-replace patterns, with, e.g., multiple groups or different text.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it was the second case, the blanks had to be substituted. In any case it worked.

But now I have another challenge... I have to replace the last 9 blanks of the string with "/ [ yea ]", with the slash! Any ideas?

Comment: I've expanded the explanation, which will hopefully let you better generalize the command. For your modification, you just need to extend the string of spaces to be 9 long and the replacement text to `\\ [ yea ]`.

Comment: BTW, a couple of tips, since you're a new user. On Stack Overflow, one says thanks by upvoting and/or accepting answers. Similarly, it's better to modify or clarify a question by editing the question, not in the comments. But don't overdo the changes to a question: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Without counting the blanks exactly:

```
echo "message         foo" | sed "s/message        /message [ yea ]/"
```

> message [ yea ] foo

The substitute-command is 's/IN/OUT/', while 'm...' is unknown - no m-command known. Another key to success, is, to mask the single character [ immediately, without a blank in between, with a backslash. However - on the right side of a substitution-expression, a group does not make much sense, so you don't need to mask them.

Comment: In the text. Check the edit I made to see if it matches your intent. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Yes, I see. If you see a typo, you can correct it, if it is not unclear whether it was made intentionally. I will remove my first comment as 'discussion noise' now.